# How to check if a file is open and/or being edited in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, inotify

I need to write a script to check if a file is open and/or being edited in Linux shell and advise the user. I tried to use `inotifywait`, but I'm begginer in Linux and I could not have some results. Could someone bring me a light?

Answer (score 1):

The **lsof** helps to figure out if a file is open or not. 
You can use

> lsof -c gedit

I would like you to go through the below link :
[Files are open or not](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof)

This is a sample script for your reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    if ! [[ `lsof | grep filename.ext` ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
echo "done"
```